# Retrieve response errors with axioson 400 and 401 status code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I´m trying to authenticate using axios, but when is error 400 or 401, in the cases of missing or wrong email and password I can't get the response message from the API, console logging axios error only shows me this:

> error => Error: Request failed with status code 400
> at createError (1.chunk.js:104463)
> at settle (1.chunk.js:104697)
> at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (1.chunk.js:103940)

Dont know how to get the proper response, which is this:
{"errors":[{"message":"Please supply e-mail and password."}]}

Here is my code

```
(...)

axios.post('some api for authentication',
        {
            email: formData.email,
            password: formData.password,
            remember: formData.remember
        })
        .then(response => {
          token = response.data.session.user
          console.log('response =>', token)
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          token = null
          console.log('error =>', error)
        })

(...)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you tried to convert the object you send JSON and test?

Comment: can you show us some backend code ?

Comment: You shared an error `{"errors":[{"message":"Please supply e-mail and password."}]}`. What types is `errors`? Which element of that type has the error? Which property on that element has the error message string? Is the issue accessing/finding an element in an array?

Comment: I dont know @AlexanderStaroselsky because I dont catch the error in axios, I can see this in chrome devtools as the response of the request. My problem is that I cant get this message in the error object of axios "catch"

Comment: Looking at axios documentation it has a section on handling [errors](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors). Try logging `console.log(error.response.data);` in the `catch`.

Comment: I tested that before without success but tested now, and it worked! I should have had a typo or something. Thanks @AlexanderStaroselsky

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per axios [handling errors](https://github.com/axios/axios#handling-errors) the underlying error data such as `message` should be available at `error.response.data`:

```
.catch((error) => {
  token = null
  console.log('error =>', error.response.data)
});
```

You may want to use the example and handle different types of errors tht can happen:

```
.catch(function (error) {
  if (error.response) {
    // The request was made and the server responded with a status code
    // that falls out of the range of 2xx
    console.log(error.response.data);
    console.log(error.response.status);
    console.log(error.response.headers);
  } else if (error.request) {
    // The request was made but no response was received
    // `error.request` is an instance of XMLHttpRequest in the browser and an instance of
    // http.ClientRequest in node.js
    console.log(error.request);
  } else {
    // Something happened in setting up the request that triggered an Error
    console.log('Error', error.message);
  }
    console.log(error.config);
});
```

Hopefully that helps!